# Здравствуйте, можно сказать я киплю?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, можно сказать я киплю?

Answer (score 2):

Да, так можно сказать. См. примеры такого употребления.

Яблоки собирать надо, а я с ними пять дней как ***в котле киплю.*** [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 2 (1964)

***Киплю негодованием:*** уже не то обидно, что легкомысленно по старушечьей линии понеслась, а ― что, и старухой будучи, вероломно мне изменил.

Мы ездили всей группой помогать на стройку, и я там разругалась вдрызг. До сих ***пор вся киплю!*** ― Сначала сядь. [И. А. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы (1959-1963)]

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно.

> Сергей Михалков "Лапуся"
>
> ...
>
> Я такое обращенье
>
> Ненавижу, не терплю,
>
> Я киплю от возмущенья
>
> И поэтому грублю.

Comment: Почему же глагол кипеть не имеет форм 1 и 2 лица ед.ч. и мн.ч.?( Ожегов)

Comment: @Надежда Простите, не понял?

Comment: @Надежда, обратите внимание, что в указанном вами словаре форма ед.ч. есть. КИПЕ́ТЬ, -плю, -пишь; несовер. 1. (1-ое лицо и 2-е лицо не употр.). О жидкости: бурлить, клокотать, испаряясь от сильного нагрева.  1-ое лицо и 2-е лицо не употр. в том случае, если речь идет о жидкости.